# How to mark the region of interest (wound) without covering the currency?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to calculate the size of a wound. For that, I am capturing an image with a coin that serves as a basis to know the scale of the image and calculate the size of the region of the wound. I'm using the watershed algorithm for segmentation, but the currency is being covered by the tracking. Can someone help me get around the coin and detach it from the image along with the wound area.

Input
[image]

[image]

Exit:
[image]

[image]
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

```
# Read the image and perfrom an OTSU threshold
img = cv2.imread('feridatest.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Remove hair with opening
kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)

# Combine surrounding noise with ROI
kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
dilate = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)

# Blur the image for smoother ROI
blur = cv2.blur(dilate,(5,5))

# Perform another OTSU threshold and search for biggest contour
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Create a new mask for the result image
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# Draw the contour on the new mask and perform the bitwise operation
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# Display the result
cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Input
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Exit:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Comment: I don't get what purpose the coin serves. Clearly it's just pasted over image, so it brings zero calibration information. In fact to paste correctly you need to know the pixel size. It does not seem likely that the real-world photo will have a coin.

Comment: What do you mean by `"but the currency is being covered by the tracking."` Have you tried color thresholding on the skin tones using cv2.inRange()

Comment: the code that makes the comparison between the size of the coin and the image has not been added, but it is already done. Today I want to first solve this segmentation problem, to later run the wound calculation based on the currency